# traceview crashes with no reason

Tags: android, debugging, crash

Traceview crashes with no reason if i try to open a collected tracefile. I checked it with older trace-files, then it opens. But every new trace i record crashes with something like

```
Traceview: ThreadData: 'java/lang/String.equals (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z' call time
 (-8057) is less than previous time (763) for thread '[1] main'
Traceview: ThreadData: 'org/apache/harmony/dalvik/ddmc/DdmVmInternal.getThreadSt
ats ()[B' call time (-4883) is less than previous time (881439) for thread '[5]
JDWP'
```

I try to trace an AsyncTask. When i open traceview from within eclipse, whole eclipse crashes.

Anybody has a solution to the problem?

Comment: What version of Android?  Are you running on the emulator or a device (and if the latter, which one)?  Are you collecting trace data with a debugger attached?

Comment: debugger isn't attached. android on htc hero device is 2.3.1 custom rom. Build target is 2.2

Comment: That's weird.  If you have a copy of dmtracedump (dalvik/tools/dmtracedump/ in the main source tree, might be in the SDK?), you can use "dmtracedump -o foo.trace" to get a raw dump of the file and see what the timestamps look like.

Comment: That does not work too. This tool crashes wit: ERROR: unable to read 8606823 bytes from trace file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give me an answer myself. The cause was that custom ROM which didn't work. It was strange that the emulator did not work too, but installing another custom ROM solved the problem.

This official ticket for android helped me: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4287

Comment: Ah, I vaguely remember that one.  Never did learn why the custom ROM was behaving so strangely.  FWIW, if dmtracedump won't accept the file it suggests that the file itself is damaged (e.g. truncated).